# Div is jumpy with fadeIn jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I roll over .comptext_rollover div it should hide the initial div on the page and show the minipage div. but it does but is sometimes really jumpy and also the minipage div sometimes shows below the initialpage div. any ideas? sorry i am new to coding! Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#mini_page').hide();

    $('.comptext_rollover').hover(function() {
        $('#initial_page').hide();
        $('.register_button').hide();
        $('#mini_page').fadeIn(100);
        $('#container').css({
            'margin-top': '-217px'
        });

    }, function() {

        $('#mini_page').hide();
        $('#initial_page').show();
        $('.register_button').show();
        $('#container').css({
            'margin-top': '-150px'
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: It is often useful to include a live example to help people better understand your problem - http://jsfiddle.net/ - works great.

Comment: http://bouncebubble.com/v1.6/ this is what it is but i want the mini to fade in without any jumping

Answer (score 1):

I prepared a fiddle demo **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/wECav/5/)**

**re-EDIT**:

### [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/R3Sjm/5/)

(the demo may be incorrect while the main CSS is an external link)
I used:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="initial_page" class="page">
        <div id="playvideo_hoverbutton"></div>
        <div class="register_button"></div>
        <div id="invisible_register2"></div>

        <div id="termsandconditionsapplyshort"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="mini_page" class="page">
        <div id="minicar_animated"></div>
        <div id="worth25k"></div>
        <div class="register_button"></div>
        <div id="invisible_register"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- THE ROLLOVER IS OUT OF ALL 'PAGES'! -->
    <div class="comptext_rollover">
    <!--<div id="competition_text"></div>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#mini_page').hide();

$('.comptext_rollover').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.page').fadeToggle(400);
});

$('.comptext_rollover').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.page').fadeToggle(400);
});
```

In any case what you should do:

Position `absolute` the 2 screens you need to 'swap' into a container.
Than what you do:

Position the 'rollover' element outside the 'screens'.

Adjust the marginTop of the bigger image(car image) in the CSS (like I did) to fix the buggy 'jumps'.

- IF POSSIBLE: ONLY ONE rollover ACTION ELEMENT!
- Fix the margin-top of the car image. (give it a -Npx)
- Doing so you don't need to do that stuff with positioning your container -Npx

There is also a simpler way to do the same effect:
you add to BOTH screens a class .swappable, making the second one (CSS)`display:none;` , and than you just use jQuery toggling just this class.

Comment: Thanks Graham! yes I took some time ripping it out too! :)

Comment: thanks thats great thanks both of you i will change my code now and show you later

Comment: @HAWKES08 wow! glad you like it! Yes, you'll have to make a remake of your css a bit. And make us know when you're done, we'll jump to the site to give it a look! :)

Comment: @HAWKES08 hahahah i'm struggling with your online CSS! STOOOP! look now!

Answer (score 0):

you've not set a great deal of time for the fade in. you're also just hiding some of the divs which makes the fade in move around depending on where you put them. maybe use slides instead. I have saved an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/kBEUH/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mini_page').hide();
    $('.comptext_rollover').hover(function () {
        $('#initial_page').fadeOut(1000);
        $('.register_button').fadeOut(1000);
        $('#mini_page').slideDown(1000);

  }, function(){
        $('#mini_page').slideUp(1000);
        $('#initial_page').fadeIn(1000);
        $('.register_button').fadeIn(1000);

  });
});
```

Comment: set the fade in to a greater time         $('#mini_page').fadeIn(500);  (nice site)

Comment: its still really buggy when i do that u have uploaded it to show you.

Answer (score 0):

if you put a `console.log` in your hover() function, you'll see hover is firing like crazy. This causes the animation to start over and over again, while moving your mouse.

You could take advantage of the jquery [:animated](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) selector:

```
$('.comptext_rollover').hover(function() {

    //enable this line to see the hover event is firing every time your mouse moves
    //console.log("hovering")

    //if the div is in the middle of an animation, do nothing
    if (!$("#mini_page").is(":animated")) {

        $('#initial_page').hide();
        $('.register_button').hide();
        $('#mini_page').fadeIn(100);
        $('#container').css({
            'margin-top': '-217px'
        });

    }

}, function() {

    //etc

});
```

**EDIT:**
Now I think of it, your probably want to use [.mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [.mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead of hover()

```
$('.comptext_rollover').mouseenter(function() {
    //your code
}).mouseleave(function() {
    //your code
});
```

Comment: I thought that too, but I think it's because the div the event is attached to is being hidden and shown again that's causing the problem. Just looking at restructuring the html to always have it on the page

Comment: i have done that code now:
please have a look at what it is doing - www.bouncebubble.com/v1.6